# Inkscape Pattern along path generate repeated outline and not fill

Tags: inkscape, path, patterns, path-effects

New to Inkscape,

I want to make a "binary film reel strip",
so I found a film slide SVG in publicdomainvectors,
and want it to repeat on a path.

1. I drag the SVG on the canvas
2. select and copy the slide
3. draw a path and add Path Effect : "Pattern along path"
4. I get only the outline, and not the content
   (I could get the content before, but I don't know exactly what I did to achieve that.
   furthermore, it did not ever repeat the 101010101 text in the slide)
   [[image: This is what i got :]1]

I tried converting everything to paths, also to pattern, with and without grouping.

please help!
how can I repeat a pattern in it's whole, and not only it's outline?

Edit:
Thanks to @BillyKer answer, I got a bit further, but still not what i try to achieve (and not as Billy's example shows)

1. Ungrouped everything
2. convert to path
3. ungroup again
4. convert to path again
5. path>combine
6. copy
7. apply as repeated pattern

This is what I got:
details are shown now, but as outline of the detail :\

any idea what I'm doing wrong?
[image: details are shown, but still as outline of the detail]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the graphic to a combined path first.

1. Ungroup it until there are no groups left, select all of it and click *Path > Combine*.
2. Now, copy it
3. Add the pattern along a path effect, then in the path effects, set to "Repeated".

[image]

Comment: Thanks,  That makes sense. I'll try as soon i will be at my pc.

Comment: tried it, now i can see the detail, but not as a FILL, but as outline (updated question)

Comment: @TomerW You appear to have added a stroke. Instead just change the fill colour, after you've applied the pattern to the path.

Comment: yeeaaaahhh.. thats it :)))